# How to add elements revealed by click action to elements list in Excel VBA for an html web form

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to set up an Excel form that auto-fills an HTML web form. I've figured out how to use VBA to get the elements and cycle through them to add values. My issue is with a text field that is revealed with the click of a check box. I can't have Excel check the box until after I've obtained the elements for the form.

I've looked at the html, and it looks like the field is hidden to some degree when the form is first loaded, as the id and everything can only be found in the tree once the box is checked. The problem is, this field won't show up in the VBA elements list no matter what I try. I've tried re-doing the Set command, and gotten an error when I do that. I'm not sure how to refresh the elements list in VBA to include the new input box.

I used the `Set` command to get all the elements

`Set frm = ie.document.getElementByID("form1")`

This is fine, but I can't use that same command to try to re-Set the element list. I get the run-time error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method)

I tried making a Variant titled `frm2`, but I get the same error

```
Sub formFill()
    Dim ie      As Object
    Dim frm     As Variant
    Dim element As Variant

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.navigate "THIS IS THE URL"
    While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    'Get form by ID
    Set frm = ie.document.getElementByID("form1")

    ie.Visible = True

    For Each element In frm.elements

        Select Case element.Name
            Case "fv_RRFC$chkOtherModel"
                element.Checked = True
                element.FireEvent ("OnClick")
                frm.getElementByID("fv_RRFC_txtOtherModel")(0).Value = "test model" 'I tried using the command here, but it didn't work
            Case "fv_RRFC$txtRRFC_PROGRAM"
                element.Value = "test"
            Case "fv_RRFC$txtOtherModel"
                element.Value = "test model"
                'My attempt to add it to the Select Case. Not surprised this didn't work, as the for Each loop uses the list it had before
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

I expected to be able to re-load the elements list to interact and fill the newly revealed box, but I've had no luck finding a way to do that.

Comment: Have you tried to: after your `element.FireEvent ("OnClick")`, set `frm` to `nothing`. Then try to reset it to: `Set frm = ie.document.getElementByID("form1")`. Make sure that `form1` still exists

Comment: Possibly need a wait after `element.FireEvent ("OnClick")`?

Comment: Just noticed, you are using `getElementById` and are trying to access an index in it. `getElementById` only returns a single node not an array of nodes. This is because `id` in HTML has to be unique. Try removing the index: `frm.getElementByID("fv_RRFC_txtOtherModel").Value = "test model"`

Comment: I tried using getElementById with no index and had the same issue. I had added the index to see if that would fix it and forgot to remove it. I tried setting frm  to nothing, and it then gives Runtime error 91 (Object variable or With block variable not set). Even if I add a While ie.readyState <> 4 : DoEvents : Wend after the FireEvent ("OnClick"), I still get the Runtime Error 438

Comment: @gramzad, Try to create an object of document and after showing the field on the page again try to assign that object and check whether it helps to find the new elements on the page or not.